# how to process XMLHttpRequest at server side with asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I plan to use XMLHttpRequest "post" text/string to server from client side. I need the text/string to be saved. I am new to XMLHttpRequest. I see a lot javascript coding but few server side coding. How can I process XMLHttpRequest at server side with asp.net/c#? Many thanks.

```
xhr.open("POST", "processing.aspx", true); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", " "); 
var data = " ";                 
xhr.send(data);
```

this is the javascript code to send data. I need some code example "processing.aspx" to save data at server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post to a web method like below using javascript.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static object GetData(string strFromHttpRequest)
    {

        return yourData;
    }
```

here is a good tutorial to sart.
http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/XMLHTTPRequest/XMLHTTPRequest_236.aspx

Comment: I tried, but never hits the server-side function. any idea why?